# Insert folder-segment into URL via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to insert a folder-segment into the URL if the site is requested with an other explicit folder-segment.

Example:

`http://www.domain.tld/people/xyz` to `http://www.domain.tld/en/people/xyz`

The premiss for this logic is that it should only rewrite this if the segment /people/ in the original request is given. The appended xyz is variable.

Could anyone solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(people/.*) /en/$1 [R,L]
```

`/people/` must be present at the start of the requested URL for this to redirect.

Change the `R` to `R=301` if this is intended to be a permanent redirect, only after you have confirmed it's working OK.